# Cartesian to Spherical Coordinates

Tags: integration

Can someone help me passing this triple integral from cartesian to spherical coordinates ?

Thanks in advance ;)

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2
{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}$$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}r^4\cdot r^2\sin(\varphi){\mathrm{d} r}{\mathrm{d} \theta }{\mathrm{d} \varphi }$$ was what I did, but I am not so sure if it is right.

Comment: @emanuelcamacho You're very close.  The projection onto the $x-y$ plane covers only Quadrant 1, while the surfaces between $z=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ and $z=\sqrt(2-x^2-y^2)$ is in Octant 1 only.  So, the limit on the polar angle extends from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and not to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the region of interest is bounded by $0\le r \le \sqrt{2}$, $0\le \theta \le \pi/4$, and $0\le \phi \le \pi/2$, where $\theta$ is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle.  The integral is thus given by

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}r^6dr\,\sin \theta\,d\theta \,d\phi$$